# Where can I find the max block size in the protocol parameters?

Tags: cardano-cli, blockchain, blocksize

I know the actual block size is 88KB but I can't find this value in the protocol parameters.

I have ran this command in Testnet and got the following:

```
$ cardano-cli query protocol-parameters --testnet-magic 1097911063
{
    "maxValueSize": 5000,
    "minUTxOValue": null,
    "minPoolCost": 340000000,
    "monetaryExpansion": 3.0e-3,
    "stakeAddressDeposit": 2000000,
    "txFeeFixed": 155381,
    "poolRetireMaxEpoch": 18,
    "stakePoolDeposit": 500000000,
    "maxBlockExecutionUnits": {
        "memory": 80000000,
        "steps": 40000000000
    },
    "extraPraosEntropy": null,
    "stakePoolTargetNum": 500,
    "maxBlockHeaderSize": 1100,
    "maxCollateralInputs": 3,
    "txFeePerByte": 44,
    "treasuryCut": 0.2,
    "protocolVersion": {
        "minor": 0,
        "major": 6
    },
    "collateralPercentage": 150,
    "poolPledgeInfluence": 0.3,
    "costModels": {
        "PlutusScriptV1": {
            "mapData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "lessThanInteger-memory-arguments": 1,
            "sha3_256-cpu-arguments-slope": 82363,
            "bData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "equalsByteString-cpu-arguments-intercept": 112536,
            "equalsString-cpu-arguments-constant": 1000,
            "modInteger-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "equalsInteger-memory-arguments": 1,
            "trace-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "iData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "equalsByteString-memory-arguments": 1,
            "unIData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "consByteString-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "cekLamCost-exBudgetCPU": 29773,
            "indexByteString-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "cekStartupCost-exBudgetMemory": 100,
            "listData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "divideInteger-cpu-arguments-constant": 148000,
            "lessThanInteger-cpu-arguments-intercept": 179690,
            "verifySignature-cpu-arguments-slope": 1,
            "appendString-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "equalsString-cpu-arguments-slope": 1000,
            "blake2b-cpu-arguments-intercept": 2477736,
            "encodeUtf8-cpu-arguments-slope": 1000,
            "mapData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "equalsByteString-cpu-arguments-slope": 247,
            "multiplyInteger-cpu-arguments-intercept": 61516,
            "cekStartupCost-exBudgetCPU": 100,
            "sndPair-memory-arguments": 32,
            "sha3_256-cpu-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "addInteger-cpu-arguments-slope": 0,
            "constrData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "divideInteger-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "cekForceCost-exBudgetCPU": 29773,
            "equalsByteString-cpu-arguments-constant": 150000,
            "modInteger-cpu-arguments-model-arguments-intercept": 425507,
            "sliceByteString-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "equalsString-memory-arguments": 1,
            "cekLamCost-exBudgetMemory": 100,
            "lessThanEqualsInteger-cpu-arguments-intercept": 145276,
            "quotientInteger-memory-arguments-minimum": 1,
            "consByteString-cpu-arguments-intercept": 150000,
            "appendByteString-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "lessThanByteString-cpu-arguments-slope": 248,
            "lessThanByteString-memory-arguments": 1,
            "multiplyInteger-cpu-arguments-slope": 11218,
            "cekVarCost-exBudgetCPU": 29773,
            "cekDelayCost-exBudgetMemory": 100,
            "blake2b-cpu-arguments-slope": 29175,
            "mkNilData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "appendByteString-cpu-arguments-slope": 621,
            "appendString-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "lessThanInteger-cpu-arguments-slope": 497,
            "chooseUnit-memory-arguments": 32,
            "divideInteger-cpu-arguments-model-arguments-slope": 118,
            "decodeUtf8-cpu-arguments-slope": 1000,
            "chooseData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "verifySignature-cpu-arguments-intercept": 3345831,
            "modInteger-memory-arguments-minimum": 1,
            "lessThanEqualsByteString-memory-arguments": 1,
            "quotientInteger-cpu-arguments-constant": 148000,
            "consByteString-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "tailList-memory-arguments": 32,
            "divideInteger-cpu-arguments-model-arguments-intercept": 425507,
            "decodeUtf8-cpu-arguments-intercept": 150000,
            "lessThanEqualsInteger-memory-arguments": 1,
            "appendByteString-cpu-arguments-intercept": 396231,
            "unMapData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "chooseList-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "divideInteger-memory-arguments-minimum": 1,
            "unListData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "remainderInteger-cpu-arguments-constant": 148000,
            "addInteger-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "sha3_256-memory-arguments": 4,
            "lessThanByteString-cpu-arguments-intercept": 103599,
            "modInteger-cpu-arguments-constant": 148000,
            "lessThanEqualsInteger-cpu-arguments-slope": 1366,
            "appendByteString-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "listData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "ifThenElse-memory-arguments": 1,
            "cekApplyCost-exBudgetMemory": 100,
            "sliceByteString-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "unIData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "modInteger-cpu-arguments-model-arguments-slope": 118,
            "equalsData-cpu-arguments-intercept": 150000,
            "mkNilPairData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "cekConstCost-exBudgetCPU": 29773,
            "indexByteString-memory-arguments": 1,
            "blake2b-memory-arguments": 4,
            "lessThanEqualsByteString-cpu-arguments-slope": 248,
            "cekDelayCost-exBudgetCPU": 29773,
            "multiplyInteger-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "remainderInteger-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "subtractInteger-cpu-arguments-slope": 0,
            "iData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "cekBuiltinCost-exBudgetCPU": 29773,
            "mkNilData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "cekForceCost-exBudgetMemory": 100,
            "trace-memory-arguments": 32,
            "encodeUtf8-cpu-arguments-intercept": 150000,
            "sha2_256-cpu-arguments-intercept": 2477736,
            "headList-memory-arguments": 32,
            "unBData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "remainderInteger-memory-arguments-minimum": 1,
            "unMapData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "sha2_256-cpu-arguments-slope": 29175,
            "modInteger-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "ifThenElse-cpu-arguments": 1,
            "tailList-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "multiplyInteger-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "remainderInteger-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "consByteString-cpu-arguments-slope": 1000,
            "lengthOfByteString-memory-arguments": 4,
            "fstPair-memory-arguments": 32,
            "mkPairData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "appendString-cpu-arguments-intercept": 150000,
            "verifySignature-memory-arguments": 1,
            "sliceByteString-cpu-arguments-intercept": 150000,
            "equalsData-cpu-arguments-slope": 10000,
            "lessThanEqualsByteString-cpu-arguments-intercept": 103599,
            "chooseList-memory-arguments": 32,
            "nullList-memory-arguments": 32,
            "unListData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "equalsData-memory-arguments": 1,
            "quotientInteger-cpu-arguments-model-arguments-slope": 118,
            "sha2_256-memory-arguments": 4,
            "quotientInteger-cpu-arguments-model-arguments-intercept": 425507,
            "encodeUtf8-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "quotientInteger-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "unConstrData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "sliceByteString-cpu-arguments-slope": 5000,
            "cekBuiltinCost-exBudgetMemory": 100,
            "equalsInteger-cpu-arguments-slope": 1326,
            "subtractInteger-memory-arguments-slope": 1,
            "mkCons-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "chooseUnit-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "chooseData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "bData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "appendString-cpu-arguments-slope": 1000,
            "decodeUtf8-memory-arguments-slope": 8,
            "fstPair-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "unConstrData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "sndPair-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "addInteger-memory-arguments-intercept": 1,
            "cekConstCost-exBudgetMemory": 100,
            "remainderInteger-cpu-arguments-model-arguments-intercept": 425507,
            "equalsString-cpu-arguments-intercept": 150000,
            "mkCons-memory-arguments": 32,
            "mkPairData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "lengthOfByteString-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "remainderInteger-cpu-arguments-model-arguments-slope": 118,
            "cekApplyCost-exBudgetCPU": 29773,
            "constrData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "nullList-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "headList-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "decodeUtf8-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "subtractInteger-cpu-arguments-intercept": 197209,
            "subtractInteger-memory-arguments-intercept": 1,
            "encodeUtf8-memory-arguments-slope": 8,
            "equalsInteger-cpu-arguments-intercept": 136542,
            "quotientInteger-memory-arguments-intercept": 0,
            "cekVarCost-exBudgetMemory": 100,
            "unBData-memory-arguments": 32,
            "addInteger-cpu-arguments-intercept": 197209,
            "mkNilPairData-cpu-arguments": 150000,
            "divideInteger-memory-arguments-slope": 1
        }
    },
    "maxTxExecutionUnits": {
        "memory": 16000000,
        "steps": 10000000000
    },
    "executionUnitPrices": {
        "priceSteps": 7.21e-5,
        "priceMemory": 5.77e-2
    },
    "decentralization": 0,
    "utxoCostPerWord": 34482,
    "maxTxSize": 16384,
    "maxBlockBodySize": 98304
}
```

I have looked for `90112` (since that's `88 * 1024` - in bytes), but no luck either.

What's the right way of getting the max block size from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this info from the live chain `protocol-parameters` and filter on the string **block**, as per below:

```
$ cardano-cli query protocol-parameters --mainnet |grep -i block
    "maxBlockExecutionUnits": {
    "maxBlockHeaderSize": 1100,
    "maxBlockBodySize": 90112
```

90112 / 1024 = 88KB

Comment: Ok, this is exactly what I was doing. So basically what this is telling me is that the maxBlockBodySize in Testnet is 96KB (98304 / 1024) instead of 88KB bytes. Is this correct?

Comment: I haven't tried this on testnet, but if you're getting 98304 then yeah it looks like they are running with a larger block size when compared to mainnet.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the wrong place. You are looking at the genesis config for one of the eras (Alonzo maybe?).

The `max_block_size` is set in the on-chain epoch paramaters which `cardano-db-sync` stores in the `epoch_param` table. My `db-sync` is only synced to epoch `336` so I do not get the latest epochs:

```
select epoch_no, max_block_size from epoch_param where epoch_no >= 320 order by epoch_no ;
 epoch_no | max_block_size 
----------+----------------
      320 |          81920
      321 |          81920
      322 |          81920
      323 |          81920
      324 |          81920
      325 |          81920
      326 |          81920
      327 |          81920
      328 |          81920
      329 |          81920
      330 |          81920
      331 |          81920
      332 |          81920
      333 |          81920
      334 |          81920
      335 |          90112
      336 |          90112
(17 rows)
```